# Log of wireless connections

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, logs

Is there any way to view a log of when I connected and disconnected with a certain wireless network?

I am trying to find the date/time and either the MAC address or SSID of the access points for some connections yesterday morning.

I am using Linux Mint 17.3 with network-manager-gnome.

Answer (score -1):

I normally use `dmesg | grep <used module>` to show the kernel messages related to the used module.